# I am getting multiple SLF4J bindings warnings and Error starting handlers and NoSuchMethodError when using JAX-WS

Tags: java, jax-ws, slf4j

I am getting  **multiple SLF4J bindings warnings** and **Error starting handlers**  and **NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V**

Everything was fine ,once I started  using JAX-WS, all this business appeared.

One of my colleague got same error but once he removed the jar(jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8)it is fine for him now,

But I tried same not working for me.

I tried to remove the following  jars  one by one present in my classpath 1.slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar    2.  slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar and  3.slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar   but no effect.

When I tried maven clean before running Jetty it was showing build error and unable to to delete (xmlsec-1.4.4.jar),I manually removed this jar still not building anything to my .M2 repository.

Here is the console output:

```
        2011-12-23 08:44:55.765:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/My_workspace/my_portal            /MyPortal/trunk/MyPortalWebApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-        log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/My_workspace/MyPortal/trunk/MyPortalWebApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2011-12-23 08:44:57.140:INFO:/MyPortalWebApp:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2011-12-23 08:44:57.140:WARN::failed org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@c4fe76    {/MyPortalWebApp,C:\My_workspace\MyPortal\trunk\MyPortalWebApp\src\main\webapp}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
2011-12-23 08:44:57.140:WARN::Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:187)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized        (ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:82)
```

Please give me some input I tried lot of permutations but getting the same (as above) output when Running Jetty.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is including automatically different versions of slf4j-api and either slf4j-log4j or slf4j-logging.  You can find out why they are being included by typing:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.slf4j
```

Since you're using Jetty, it may also be that Jetty is including the container's classpath with your app.  Try adding the following line (if it's Jetty 6 or older) to your webapp's context file:

```
<Set name="parentLoaderPriority">false</Set>
```

It should set the container jars and resources to be lower priority than your webapp ones.

Answer (score 0):

You still have `slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar` in your classpath (at `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar`) according to the error message. What tool (Ant, Maven) are you using for your build process?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like caused by incompatible versions of slf4j being loaded.Try this

```
-In eclipse, open the pom.xml file.
-select the Dependency Hierarchy tab at the bottom. 
-In the search filter, type the name "slf4j" and see all the dependencies that depend on slf4j for logging.
```

If you find multiple times, then you can exclude it by writing this in each dependency

```
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <artifactId>[artifactId]</artifactId>
        <groupId>[groupId]</groupId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```